# Can someone check/help with these anti-derivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration

I understand the basics of anti-derivatives, and have been given the following questions:

1: $ \int [t^3 - 5e^t - 4\cos(t)] dt $

My answer:

> $ \frac{t^4}{4} - e^{5t} + \sin(4t) + c $

2: $ \int [\frac{8}{x} + 5\sec(x)\tan(x)] dx$

My answer:

> $8\ln(x) + \sec^2(5x) + c$

3: $ \int \frac{4x}{(x^2 +5)^3} dx $

My answer:

> None yet, slightly confused since it's a quotient.

4: $ \int [x^2 \sqrt{2x^2 + 5}]  dx $

My answer:

> None yet, confused as well.

So I'm wondering if someone can check number 1 & 2, and then explain/show 3 & 4?

**EDIT**

These are what I get when I redo them (I've done my best to just look at suggestions rather than answers):

1: $ \frac{t^4}{4} - 5e^t - 4sin(t) + c $

2: $ 8ln(x) + 5sec(x) + c $

3: $ 2 \frac{(x^2 + 5)^{-2}}{-2}$

4: $ \frac{1}{6} \frac{(2x^3 + 5)^{3/2}}{3/2}$

Comment: The first one is wrong. The second has a small error. You can check the result of an integration yourself, by differentiating. For the third, let $u=x^2+5$.

Comment: Yeah. 1 is wrong. It should be $\frac{t^4}{4}-5e^{t}-4\sin t +c$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In 1. is the issue $-e^5t$? As for 2. Is it $sec(5x)$ instead of $sec^2(5x)$

Comment: The integral of $\sec x\tan x$ is $\sec x$.

Comment: So the answer in 2 is $8\ln x+5\sec x +c$

Comment: To transform the integrand in 4 into a rational fraction of $t$ use the [Euler substitution](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euler_substitutions) $$\sqrt{2x^2+5}=\sqrt{2}x+t.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1$ and $2$ are not quite right. You seem to understand the idea but are missing one thing:

The derivative of for example $\sin(4t)$ by the chain rule would be $4 \cos(4t)$ not $4 \cos(t)$.  This should show you why you shouldn't bring the constant inside the function you're taking the antiderivative of.

### In general if you have a constant multiplied by a function you should take the antiderivative as if the constant were not there, and then multiply that by the constant.

For example for $4 \cos(t)$, we'll ignore the $4$ and take the antiderivative of $\cos(t)$ which is $\sin(t)$, then multiply it by $4$ to get $$ 4 \sin(t).$$
To check that this will work you should take the derivative and make sure its the what you want it to be!

You have made this error a couple if times in the first two and I advice you to try and find all the places you have and fix it.

For problem $3$ I advise you to try the $u$-sub $ u = x^2 + 5$.

And for problem $4$ I think the integral is intended to be $x^2\sqrt{2x^3 + 5}$ in which case I would suggest the $u$-sub $u = 2x^3 + 5$.

Comment: For problem 4. If u = $2x^3 + 5$, then du = $6x^2$. How do I deal with du when plugging it in?

Comment: @StrugglingWithMath Yes you are right it will be $\frac{1}{6}\mathrm{d}u$! You have $\mathrm{d}u = 6x^2 \mathrm{d}x$, so $\frac{1}{6} \mathrm{d}u = x^2 \mathrm{d}x$, you see that $x^2 \mathrm{d}x$ is in the integral, so replace that with $\frac{1}{6} \mathrm{d}u$!

Comment: So: $\frac{1}{6}du * u^{1/2}$ which is $ \frac{1}{6} \frac{u^{3/2}}{3/2}$ then plug $2x^3+5$ back in for u?

Comment: @StrugglingWithMath yep thats right!

Comment: To transform the integrand in 4 as it is into a rational fraction of $t$ we can use the [Euler substitution](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euler_substitutions) $$\sqrt{2x^2+5}=\sqrt{2}x+t.$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can always check whether an antiderivative is right by differentiating and checking whether you get what you started with.

For 1: Remember that $\int a f(x) \ dx = a \int f(x) \ dx$, that $\int e^x \ dx = e^x + C$ and that $(\sin x)' = \cos x$, not $-\cos x$. Also look at the derivative of $\sin(4x)$ and compare it with the derivative of $4 \sin x$.

For 2: What's the derivative of $\sec^2 x$, and what's the derivative of $\sec x$?

For 3: Try a substitution $u = x^2 + 5$.

For 4: Are you sure that's what you're supposed to do? That integral is pretty difficult, certainly not what I'd expect someone who's just starting with this to be able to do.

Comment: Similar to the question I gave Deven, but for problem 3. How do I deal with the du part since it doesn't equal what is left in the equation with u substituted in? du = 2x and there is a 4x in the original equation.

Comment: @StrugglingWithMath: since $u = x^2 + 5$, we get that $du = 2x\ dx$. But in your integral you have $4x\ dx$. Well, no problem! $4x\ dx = 2\times 2x\ dx = 2\ du$.

Comment: @StrugglingWithMath: Also, your first integral is not quite right yet, you have a sign issue. You get that the antiderivative of $-4\cos x$ is $4 \sin x$. Well, try differentiating $4\sin x$. What do you get?

Comment: #1: 4 sinx -> 4 cosx. I'll change the sign :) as for #3: $2 u^-3$ then $2 \frac{u^{-2}}{-2}$ finally $2 \frac{(x^2 + 5)^{-2}}{-2}$ Is that correct?

Comment: @StrugglingWithMath: Yes, that's right. Always remember, you can check yourself: just differentiate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely be checking them with differentiation on my exam today! By the way, I added a few upvotes elsewhere on your answers as a thanks for the help.